# React Native run-android Only works on the first build

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

The first time I run my react-native app the emulator works (using Android Studio Galaxy Nexus). However, when I close the emulator and try again I get the errors below:

```
PS C:\Users\4chea\pexhouseV2> react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1197 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
Skipping device 'emulator-5554' (emulator-5554): Device is OFFLINE.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
160 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 158 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

My emulator is open while this happens and says "failed to connect to metro server"

Answer (score 0):

This here tells you the problem.

```
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
```

Something is wrong with your emulator. Try rebooting your system. If that doesn't work, try making a new emulator and see if that one works better. Also, I would turn off the Quickstart feature on your emulator - it may ask you as you shut it down if you want to save its memory state for faster boot times. I've had issues with that in the past similar to this.

Let me know if that changes anything. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I first make a new device the emulator works perfectly. When I close the device and run the same command I start getting this error. So the emulator only works on the first try.

Comment: What happened after you tried what I suggested? Same thing? Are you making the same emulator over and over - meaning same settings/setup?